# Find closest td from another table using class

Tags: jquery, parent, closest

I have a table inside the td of another table. But I am getting length as 0 when I check the length of closest td using class. My HTML and jQuery is giev below.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <table class="table jewel_spec_table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="jewel_type_field">
                <td class="jewel_type_td">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead class="text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Jewel Type</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="jewel_type" class="form-control jewel_type">
                                        <option value="test">Test</option>
                                        <option value="test">Test</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="spec_table">

                    <p>Test</p>
                    <!-- We need content here -->

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <a class="btn-xs btn-info add_jeweltype"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I use below script to add some content to the closest td with class `spec_table`

```
$(document).on('change',".jewel_type",function(){
    $(this).closest('.spec_table').html('New content');
});
```

Any idea why it is showing 0 always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).on('change',".jewel_type",function(){
    alert($(this).parents('.jewel_type_field').find('.spec_table').length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `closest()` function is described as:

> the `.closest()` method searches through *these elements and their ancestors* in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements (emphasis mine)

It returns an empty NodeList, because the element with the `.spec_table` class is not an ancestor of `$(this)`.

To solve your task, you could select the `.jewel_spec_table` object, then make a selector on it to get the needed elements:

```
$('.jewel_spec_table').find('.spec_table')
```

This will give you the NodeList you wanted, then you can select the first item. The whole handler:

```
$(document).on('change',".jewel_type",function(){
    $('.jewel_spec_table').find('.spec_table')[0].html('New content');
});
```

Comment: `$('.jewel_spec_table').find('.spec_table')` but this would result in a collection i guess and it should be executed in the context of selector on which event is executed.

Comment: Added the whole event handler to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The element you are targeting is a sibling of closest table's parent td:

```
$(this).closest('table').parent().siblings('.spec_table').length
```

explanations:

```
$(this) // select element as per context
.closest('table') // get back to the table element
.parent() // now get the parent "td" of closest table
.siblings('.spec_table') // here you have to get the siblings of the parent td
.length // this results === 1
```

*Any idea why it is showing 0 always?*

Because you are trying to get the target element which is not accessible with `.closest()` method as in the context of your selector. You can see when it gets executed what happens:

```
$(this) // current element which is select
.closest('.spec_table') // doesn't have any parent with such class. so results === 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

closest function take as param: `selectors, context`.

In your case, selector is `td` and context is `.spec_table`

If you have this table:

```
<table class="spec_table">
    <tr>
        <td>123456</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Use:

```
$(document).on('change',".jewel_type",function(){
    alert($(this).parents().find('.spec_table td').length);
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/2nh63fym/

Comment: This will not work. It is giving the length of same td (where the select box is). See below  updated jsfiddle. My actual requirement is to add some content to the closest td with class .spec_table. I have updated that in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2nh63fym/2/